# Mocha test. Import class from not exported namespace

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, typescript, npm, mocha.js

I need to write unit test for my **Typescript** app. I use **Mocha test framework**.
I have got internal module(A) in my web app and class B there.

```
namespace A {
    export class B {
       constructor() {

       }
    } 
}
```

I need to write some unit test for class B.

```
/// <reference path="path/A.ts" />
import { expect } from 'chai';
    describe('B test', function () {

        describe('#constructor()', () => {
            it('Should create B with default data', () => {
                let b = new A.B();
                expect(b.age).to.equal(90);
            });

        });
    });
```

I'm starting my tests with command:

```
mocha --watch  --recursive  path/Tests
```

But every time in terminal I receive error message:

```
ReferenceError: A is not defined
```

A - is my internal module and I can't to export it. Is it some way, how is it possible to test internal module's class B?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to reach variables from local scopes in JavaScript. Basically this is same problem as:

```
(() => {
  let bar = 1;
})();
// bar cannot be reached from this scope
```

The class needs to be refactored to be reachable:

```
export namespace A {
    export class B {
       constructor() {

       }
    } 
}
```

At this point `namespace` is of no use here, it can be omitted in favour of ES modules only.

It is a good practice to export everything for testability reasons. If a class is considered internal, it's exported from `.ts` file where it was defined but not from `index.ts`.

[`/** @internal */` JSDoc annotation and `stripInternal` compilation option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) can be used to exclude these exports from .d.ts declarations. They won't be available as regular imports but will still be reachable with `require`.

Comment: Testability is important concern and generally should outweigh project management concerns. I see nothing wrong with exporting internal units, as long as they are considered internal. I updated the answer with @internal.