# Test private function of module with mocha

Tags: typescript, testing, mocha.js

I have

MyModule.ts

```
export module MyModule {
   export function f1() {...}
   function f2() {return true}
}
```

I am trying to write some unit tests and I want to test also function f2. Unfortunately

```
let myModule = rewire('./MyModule');
let f2Function = myModule.__get__('f2');
```

I get

```
ReferenceError: f2 is not defined.
```

How can I have access to private methods?

Comment: It isn't 'private'. It's local. Variables from local scope cannot be accessed from outer scope in JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocha test. Import class from not exported namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818883/mocha-test-import-class-from-not-exported-namespace)

Comment: not in other languages also, but there are workarounds. is it possible in JS to test unexported methods or i need to export everything in order to be able to test?

Comment: Yes, everything has to be exported.